# unable to mount dvd using filesystem type in linux

Tags: linux

I have tried to mount DVD in Linux using following command:

```
sudo -u root mount -t fileSystem_type -o check=relaxed,uid=userName,gid=userName deviceID mountPoint
```

e.g.

```
sudo -u root mount -t iso9660 -o check=relaxed,uid=sdc,gid=sdc /dev/sr0 /media/mc-cddvd/
```

but it's giving error like:

```
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

So I tried: dmesg |tail command .. It gave following output :

```
sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

But I am able to mount DVD using command:
    mount /dev/sr0 /media-mc-cddvd

Is anybody faced this problem? Please give me solution.I have to use previous mount command only.

Comment: Off-topic, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is you linux system baremetal or a VM?  If it is a VM make sure that you have "attached" your dvd device.

Comment: I think the community in general and you too would benefit, should you spend some time reading about [what topics are welcome here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please consider closing your question and asking it instead in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).